# Creating a dynamic URL from a text input = Returning "undefined" in URL string

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a URL that passes an input text into a query string for an AJAX call. In the console, I can see that I'm capturing the inputted text as a string, but it's not passing into the URL and It's returning an empty object.

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="movie-title" placeholder="Enter a movie title">
    <input type="submit" id="sbmt-movie">

</form>

$("#sbmt-movie").click(function(){
    var movie = $("#movie-title").val().toLowerCase();
    console.log("the movie title is " + movie);
    var url =  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "&api_key=9b97ec8f92587c3e9a6a21e280bceba5"; 

    $.ajax ({
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);

            var list = data.list;
        }
    }); //close .ajax    
});
```

This is the information that I'm seeing in console:

XHR finished loading: GET "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=undefined&api_key=9b97ec8f92587c3e9a6a21e280bceba5".

Object {page: 1, results: Array[0], total_results: 0, total_pages: 1}

[Link to Codepen](http://codepen.io/ElaineM/pen/WQWJQa?editors=101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue lies in the line

```
var url =  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "&api_key=9b97ec8f92587c3e9a6a21e280bceba5";
```

You are trying to use the function `encodeURIComponent()` on the variable `url` which is technically not yet defined.
What I imagine you want to do instead is `encodeURIComponent(movie)`.

```
var url =  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=" + encodeURIComponent(movie) + "&api_key=9b97ec8f92587c3e9a6a21e280bceba5";
```

Take a look at my updated codepen [here](http://codepen.io/michael-hamilton/pen/megLqx?editors=101).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `url` to encodeURIComponent and not `movie`